# Why does no AVPlayerItemAudioOutput exist in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

AVPlayerItemVideoOutput is a subclass of AVPlayerItemOutput in AVFoundation, I can get the visual data in pixel buffer format and do some process. (through copyPixelBufferForItemTime:)

However, there is no AVPlayerItemAudioOutput exists accordingly. How can I process the audio data?

Do I have to use the AVAssetReader class to get this?

Comment: They're similar on the surface but both are thin wrappers around lower level C libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. `-[AVPlayerItem addOutput:]` mentions audio but there is nothing to be found on it in `AVPlayerItemOutput.h` (unless you're meant to get audio via the `AVPlayerItemLegibleOutput` class - I'm only half joking, as a class that vends `CMSampleBuffers`, I think a a hypothetical `AVPlayerItemAudioOutput` would look a lot like this).

So I don't know where `AVPlayerItemAudioOutput` is, but yes you can use `AVAssetReader` to get at audio data.

However if you're already using an `AVPlayer`, your most painless path would be using `MTAudioProcessingTap` to play the role of the hypothetical `AVPlayerItemAudioOutput`.

You can add a tap to the `inputParameters` of your `AVPlayer`'s `currentItem`'s `audioMix` to receive (and even modify) the audio of your chosen audio tracks.

It's probably easier to read [some example code](https://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/) than it is to parse what I just wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much!It's very kind of you.  I've just implemented AVPlayer and found no way to process the audio data unless I re-write it completed through AVAssetReader.I'll take a look at `MTAudioProcessingTap` and the example you posted. BTW:  What do you mean by "you're meant to get audio via the AVPlayerItemLegibleOutput class" , you mean the audio data could be got through this AVPlayerItemLegibleOutput class? How?

Comment: It seems like using `MTAudioProcessingTap` will be more painful than using AVAssetReader. I even can't find any document is ios8.2 docset.

Comment: My comment about `AVPlayerItemLegibleOutput` was a joke, now explained in the answer.